# Tracking page load time with a script/plugin - like Google Analytics, but on our own server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a script, jQuery plugin or similar that'll allow us to track and record the same statistics as the PageLoadTime option used by Google Analytics, but storing the data on our own local DB server?

We're looking to track some quite specific statistics in real-time and thinking it's probably easier to analyze local data than to be constantly exporting and analysing data from a third-party monitoring service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Yahoo Boomerang](https://github.com/yahoo/boomerang). This gathers lots of performance metrics on the client ans is well written/easy to extend.